# My MacBookPro (Sierra) not using Swap memory though no RAM is left

Tags: macos, memory, ssd, swap, macos-sierra

Recently my mac started to work very slow and constantly freezing due to running out of memory. I thought that it's supposed to use ssd space once RAM is close to full, however, it's not using the disk space enough to make some free RAM.

It does use some swap memory like 2.3gb ssd vs 7.8gb ram while over 13gb of ssd is still left.

[image: RAM vs Disk space]

[image: Activity monitor]

I do admit that I have plenty of things opened but I didn't have this issue before.

Comment: When using swap it doesn't free up RAM exactly. It "swaps" things in and out of RAM from the SSD. Say program A is using X amount of RAM then you open program B which needs more RAM than what is free. Swapping will take program A out of RAM and store it on the SSD, and put program B in RAM. If A is needed again, it will swap something out of RAM onto the SSD and bring A back into RAM. This is a very slow process in computer terms and expensive to resources. In the Windows world, this is called paging.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. But how should I deal with freezing anyway? And why did it start happening just recently (probably after upgrading to Sierra). Any ideas?

Comment: Oh yeah I guess I should have explained that part. I was tired and typing in bed and kind of forgot. Presumably the freezing is occurring during swap operations. The reasons for the freezing could be tough to pinpoint, but I'm going to go with the HDD becoming more full. Assuming this is still a problem, when an SSD becomes full, the write performance decreases a lot. This is supposedly because of how NAND flash storage works. Your disk is around 95% full so that could be a good possibility. The best guidance would be to free up space on your SSD, and close unused programs to free up RAM.

Comment: I would also look into the Google Chrome Helper process. There are a ton of those open, using a lot of RAM. If you can figure out how to decrease the number of those processes, I'm sure it would help out a lot. I'd check out [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/applehelp/comments/5mos7k/what_is_google_chrome_helper_and_why_is_it_eating/) reddit post and see if it's something you could take advantage of.

Answer (score 0):

Macs slow down dramatically when both RAM and the Hard Drive are maxed out. You may have lots of apps running in the background hog RAM, so check System Preferences > Users and Groups > Login Items to see what you have running (and remove things that you don't constantly use)

Also it would help to clean up your Hard Drive. Not only browsers, but apps have caches, so clean those up. Delete apps you don't use. Videos and images also sometimes create duplicates in various places, so locate and delete file versions in folders that don't look familiar to you. Trash - there are several places for it, as browsers and apps also have their own Trash folders - make sure you clean up those, too.

You're maxed out on memory so getting a Mac cleaner app isn't a great option, but you can check Apple Support and blogs on Mac cleaner app developers' websites for advice on manually cleaning your Mac's HD and safely removing apps that hog your RAM. Not a simple answer, but I hope it points you in a few right directions that lower your HD and RAM utilization.